AWS RUM Edge browser saves identityPoolId in cookies and creates an error on page load
I am using AWS Cloudwatch Real User Monitoring (RUM) and I added the script to my websites HTML. When I changed the Account where the data is send to, the identityPoolId in the HTML snippet changed. When I now load the website using the Edge browser and right click to inspect, I see an error (Not authorized to perform sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity). The error message says that the previous identityPoolId was used to make the request to AWS. Deleting the cookies resolved the issue for me, but I can not ask all the users to delete their cookies.
Is there a way to delete the cookie, maybe by using the "allowCookies" parameter in the HTML snippet?
Do you have any other idea how to solve this issue?
